# Fields and FieldLinks return the same two values for all Content Types

Tags: content-type

I have an application that loads all of my content types into a drop down list.  When an item in the drop down list is selected I would like to get a list of the columns for that content type but each one only returns `Title` and `ContentType`.  Here is the code I am using:

```
    protected void ddl_ContentTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPContentType ct = new SPContentType(SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Document,SPContext.Current.Web.ContentTypes,ddl_ContentTypes.SelectedValue);
        foreach (SPField f in ct.Fields)
        {
           //do stuff with each field.  Only returns Title and ContentType
        }
    }
```

Is there something I should be doing differently.  Is it bad that I am using the built in Document content type for the ParentContentType?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms480288.aspx), this construction will create new blank content type with ddl_ContentTypes.SelectedValue as it's name:

```
SPContentType ct = new SPContentType(
    SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Document,
    SPContext.Current.Web.ContentTypes,
    ddl_ContentTypes.SelectedValue);
```

What you do need, is to retrieve one of the existing content types, based on it's name. Please, try this code instead of the fragment above:

```
SPContentType ct = SPContext.Current.Web.ContentTypes[ddl_ContentTypes.SelectedValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain the difference, your original code is creating a NEW content type in the target collection `SPContext.Current.Web.ContentTypes`:

```
SPContentType ct = new SPContentType(SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Document,SPContext.Current.Web.ContentTypes,ddl_ContentTypes.SelectedValue);
```

While the code in the answer (`SPContentType ct = SPContext.Current.Web.ContentTypes[ddl_ContentTypes.SelectedValue];`) is retrieving the existing content type from the target SPWeb collection.